# How to solve such AspNetCore scenarios the correct way?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

i have

```
Singleton<ICache, LocalClusterCache>
Singleton<ICache, CloudCache>
```

in same controller i want to use both, but DI wont allow i could instead use

```
Singleton<LocalClusterCache, LocalClusterCache>
Singleton<CloudCache, CloudCache>
```

but i dont think its the correct way

Another problem:

i want a `Singleton<ICache, LocalCache>` to be different instances in InternalApiController and a different one in PublicAPIController i could use private static var inside those controllers and it would work but its not M$ 'DI' Pattern, im confused

**EDIT Solution for the first problem**

```
services.AddSingleton<ClassA>(); // same interface
services.AddSingleton<ClassB>();
// then in controller
SomeInterface classA = (ClassA)provider.GetService(typeof(ClassA));
SomeInterface classB = (ClassB)provider.GetService(typeof(ClassB));
```

that does work (not sure if its 100% proper way of doing it M$ way)

Answer (score 1):

If the dependency is contextual it's common to create an abstract factory and register that with the container for injection. This way the dependent has opportunity to pick based on something the factory exposes without immediately tying it to a concrete class.

Comment: i edited the post adding one possible solution, 
adding separate factory class adds alot of overhead (nobody wants it) 
but still have no idea how to solve the second problem, i mean   DI Singleton of the same class but separate for each controller,  could easily be done via static private property but its not DI then

Comment: @gdpm It can be just a very small class where it kind of documents your caching strategy selection, I don't see any problem with this. But sure request concrete classes, the container will help with their dependencies if any, so there i still value in doing it this way.